# Prevent event on $(this) element

Tags: javascript, jquery

A few given HTML articles like:

```
<article id="someId" class="some_wrapper">
    <section class="info_wrapper">
        <section class="info">
            <p>Content</p>
        </section>
    </section>
</article>
```

Cobined with some basic Jquery like:

```
$(".some_wrapper").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find(".info").fadeIn(500);
});

$(".some_wrapper").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find(".info").fadeOut(500);
});
```

Problem: If the user moves the mouse fast severel times from on `.some_wrapper` to another, the eventhandlers fire multiple times and build a queue of `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` effect. Those occure as long as often the handler fired, even if the mouse already stand still outside the containers.

How can I prevent the events `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` on `$(this)` element where the `.info` is visible. Or break the queue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use stop() function before trigger fadeIn or Out event

```
$(".some_wrapper").mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find(".info").stop().fadeOut(500);
    $(this).find(".info").fadeIn(500);
});

$(".some_wrapper").mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find(".info").stop().fadeIn(500);
    $(this).find(".info").fadeOut(500);
});
```

This will stop all previous fired event and execute latest event.So repeatation not occured.

Comment: Nice! How easy was that! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".some_wrapper").mouseenter(function(){
    if($(this).find(".info").is(":visible") === true) {
       $(this).find(".info").fadeIn(500);
    }
});

$(".some_wrapper").mouseleave(function(){
   if($(this).find(".info").is(":visible") === false) {
      $(this).find(".info").fadeOut(500);
   }
});
```

Comment: Using jquery .stop() function handles it better without having to add more checks